# Sending Mail via outlook with pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32

I have a quite "simple" Problem. I want to send an E-Mail with Python via opening the Local OutLook and sending it. This did work fine for a while and suddenly it stopped working. Since then I get always the same Error. I am kinda new to this and I dont know exactly what pywin is doing but I am getting there slowly.

> _GetGoodDispatch
> IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2146959355, 'Starten des Servers fehlgeschlagen', None, None)

This is my current code that worked!

```
def send_mail(adresses: List[str], subject: str="Automatic mail", body: str="I am an automatic mail",
              attachment_paths: List[str]=[]):
    """
    Send automatic mail 

    Args:
        adresses (List[str]): List of email addresses
        subject (str, optional): Email subject. Defaults to "Automatic mail".
        body (str, optional): Email body. Defaults to "I am an automatic mail".
        attachment_paths (List[str], optional): List of attachment file paths. Defaults to [].
    """
    if attachment_paths is None:
        attachment_paths = []

    outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")

    olMailItem = 0
    by_value = 1

    if isinstance(adresses, str):
        adresses = [adresses]

    for mailto in adresses:
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = 'EMAIL'
        mail.To = mailto
        mail.Subject = subject
        mail.Body = body

        for attachment_path in attachment_paths:
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment_path, by_value, 1)

        mail.Send()
```

I am kinda clueless right now what to try and when I search for the error code, then I dont find something useful.

I tried nothing special. I either tried it with an other code. I tried it with smtpltlib but did not work too. I am not a fan of sharing password data especially cause this should work in large company that I am working at right now and Engineers just want to press button Send Mail and be done and if its Local, then it would be Ideal. I found some solutions here in StackOverflow but they did not help sadly.

I tried VBS Script cause the Engineers told me that it worked with VBS fine but that did not work either but I assume that it was my fault cause I never actually programmed with it and probably did some mistakes, so if someone has a code for me that workes via VBS I would try that too.

I am open to use other coding Languges that I can call through a python script.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The error is `CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE`. Most likely this is caused by different security contexts if one of the apps (Outlook or yours) is running with  elevated privileges (Run As Administrator). Make sure neither or both do. Or make sure Outlook is not running prior to yours - Outlook is a singleton, so creating a new instance of `Outlook.Application` will always attach to the running (in different security context) first instance. If it is not running, it will be started in a context matching that of your app.

Comment: I actually found the mistake some days ago. I found out that always when you want to access Outlook with a code, then there will be an Access Token and if the Access Token is not valid anymore for example cause of an update or python update etc.(Can't really tell, it changed the token after an Outlook update by me) You can find the path of the Token with 

import win32com.client as win32 
print(win32.__gen_path__)

and all I did in the end was to delete everything that was in there and it started to work fine.